# How to capture user preference on what needs to be printed in an entity

Tags: java

How to capture user preference on what needs to be printed in an entity. We are planning to capture what information of Foo needs to be printed from Foo. The user can select A (i.e. all attributes of A, few attributes from B or C. What would be the best way to capture this information for the microservice to interpret. The attributes could get modified or removed as well on every release. We intend to create a PDF based on what was selected in the user interface

```
public class Foo {

  private A a;
  private B b;
  private C c;
}

public class A {
  private String a1, a2;
}

public class B {
  private String b1, b2, b3;
}

public class C {
  private String c1, c2, c3, c4;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just use GraphQL?

Comment: I suggest using reflection and a serializable tree structure like JSON. So you can create current snapshot of the available elements and when parsing you can ignore non existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using only built-in reflection:

```
private void test() throws Exception
{
    List<String> allProperties = getAllProperties(Foo.class,"");
    System.out.println(allProperties);
    for(String property:allProperties)
        System.out.println(property+": "+hasProperty(Bar.class, property));

    Foo bar=new Foo();
    bar.a=new A();
    bar.c=new C();
    bar.a.a1="123";
    bar.c.c3="456";

    System.out.println(getSelectedValues(bar, allProperties, ""));
}

private List<String> getSelectedValues(Object o, List<String> properties, String currentPath)
{
    List<String> values=new ArrayList<>();
    if(o!=null)
    {
        for(String property:properties)
        {
            if(!property.startsWith(currentPath) || property.length()<=currentPath.length())
                continue;

            String currentProperty=property.substring(currentPath.length());
            if(currentProperty.startsWith(".")) currentProperty=currentProperty.substring(1);
            int idx=currentProperty.indexOf('.');
            if(idx<0)
            {
                Optional.ofNullable(getProperty(o,currentProperty)).map(v->v.toString()).ifPresent(values::add);
            }
            else
            {
                currentProperty=currentProperty.substring(0, idx);
                Object v=getProperty(o,currentProperty);
                if(v!=null)
                    values.addAll(getSelectedValues(v,Collections.singletonList(property),currentPath.isEmpty()?currentProperty:(currentPath+"."+currentProperty)));
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}

private Object getProperty(Object o, String property)
{
    try
    {
        Field field = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(property);
        if(field==null) return null;
        if(!field.isAccessible())
            field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(o);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Not available or not accessible
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean hasProperty(Class<?> c, String property)
{
    try
    {
        int idx=property.indexOf('.');
        if(idx<0) // last
        {
            return c.getDeclaredField(property)!=null;
        }
        else
        {
            String head=property.substring(0,idx);
            String tail=property.substring(idx+1);

            return hasProperty(c.getDeclaredField(head).getType(),tail);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private List<String> getAllProperties(Class<?> c, String prefix)
{
    List<String> properties=new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        for(Field f:c.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            Class<?> type = f.getType();
            String name = f.getName();
            if(name.startsWith("this$"))
                continue;
            else if(type.equals(String.class))
                properties.add(prefix+name);
            else
                properties.addAll(getAllProperties(type,prefix+name+"."));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return properties;
}

public class Foo
{
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;
}

public class Bar
{
    private A a;
    private C c;
}

public class A
{
    private String a1, a2;
}

public class B
{
    private String b1, b2, b3;
}

public class C
{
    private String c1, c2, c3, c4;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear on how are you getting the preferences parameters to 'Foo'. Let's assume that you get the list of field names in 'Foo' which can contain the fields from any composition classes.

You could use the below method to print all the parameters of the object including the ones in the child class. Below is a generic method hence not modifying (You could change it as required). The input for this method in your case would be the `Foo` object and the preferences list.

```
public static void beanProperties(Object bean) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        Arrays
                .asList(Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass(), Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors())
                .stream()
                .filter(pd -> Objects.nonNull(pd.getReadMethod())).forEach(pd -> { // invoke method to get value
                    
                    try {
                        Object value = pd.getReadMethod().invoke(bean);
                        if ( value != null ) {
                            map.put(pd.getName(), value);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Used only for logging bean values, can be handled if required.
                    }
                });
        for ( Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
            log.info(String.format("%s : %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
        // Used only for logging bean values, can be handled if required.
    }
}
```

You could send in the list of preferences to this method and compare if the field is present in the list before adding it to the map.

```
if ( value != null && list.contains(pd.getName() )) {
    map.put(pd.getName(), value);
}
```